# How can I import audiobooks as audiobooks (not music)?

Tags: banshee, audiobooks

I have some audiobooks in my Audiobooks folder (~/Audiobooks). When importing them I follow this process:

- I click Audiobooks in the left hand pane.
- I right click on Audiobooks and click 'Import Media...'
- I choose to import from folders then go into my Audiobooks folder and click 'Import'
- It imports the audiobooks fine but into Music so I drag and drop them into Audiobooks - this causes them to be in both Music and Audiobooks
- I delete them from Music in Banshee and from ~/Music (because I use these settings:

  [image]

  and Banshee is copying them to ~/Music)

I now have the audiobooks in Audiobooks in the Banshee library and stored in ~/Audiobooks but the audiobooks in Banshee don't play. It seems that Banshee thinks they are still in ~/Music.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the first option, 'Copy files to media folders when importing'. If my guess is correct, this will ensure that you audiobooks stay where they are after importing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open each chapter of the audiobook with Banshee. (Be sure you've downloaded and installed all available extensions and plugins and enabled them) You will see them in your Play Que and File System Que just below Now Playing.  Then drag them into your Audiobooks.  You can then create smart playlists for Audiobooks etc. Change artwork for the audiobook (if the artwork is the correct file format etc. which it usually is if downloaded for librevox for example) Podcasts also work pretty well if you are familiar with the old rss feeds, simply look for the rss url at your favorite podcast's web page and copy to clipboard.  It should autofill when you add new Podcast.